# Como colocar informações de uma classe em um array?

Tags: c#, array, propriedade

Para economizar linhas de código, eu faço o seguinte:

```
PictureBox[] pic = { pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6, pictureBox7, pictureBox8 };
```

E eu tenho uma classe chamada `InformationLetters`, cuja a mesma tem várias variáveis, eu uso ela assim:

```
InformationLetters.Carta1 = "";, etc.
```

Para não ficar usando *IL.Carta1, IL.Carta2*...., Queria uma forma de colocá-la em uma *array*. Por exemplo:

```
Array[] Nome = { InformationLetter.Carta1, InformationLetter.Carta2 };
```

E usá-la assim:

```
Nome[0] = ""; Nome[1] = "";
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Segue o código atual e como está ocupando linhas desnecessárias:

[image: Código]

Comment: `for`s com `if`s para todos os indices estão sempre errados a nível de conceção. Sugiro que não coloque o código como imagem. [Veja aqui porquê](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485). O `InformationLetter` foi definido onde e como? O mesmo pergunto para o `CartasInformacao`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programação é sobre conceituar bem, é sobre escrever códigos significativos. Não é sobre digitar menos. O que está tentando fazer é tornar o código ilegível e criar problemas de manutenção. Não faça isso. Faça o legível.

Mas é possível que tenha um problema de engenharia aí. Não posso dar detalhes porque a pergunta não dá detalhes.

Se tem variáveis com o mesmo prefixo no nome e depois um número sequencial, talvez fosse o caso de mudar isso. Poderia usar um

```
pictureBox[i]
```

E um

```
Carta[i]
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/Array.cs).

Mesmo que queira insistir em fazer desta forma é para funcionar como está pensando em fazer, desde que essas `CartaX` sejam de um tipo por referência, porque no *array* terá uma referência para o dado igual tem em `InformationLetters.CartaX` (onde `X` aí é só uma convenção para mostrar que é o número de cada um). Eles estão acessando o mesmo objeto, portanto mudando em um lugar muda no outro.

Se o tipo for por valor só se um dia C# permitir usar `ref` no elemento do *array*. Hoje teria que criar uma infraestrutura que lidasse com isso, não acho que valha o esforço.

Se o problema é o número de linhas, cada `if` aí está ocupando 4 linhas, mas é possível ocupar 1, e se bobear fica mais legível.

Não conheço o código todo, nem tem um contexto claro, mas fico pensando se o laço da variável `j` é necessário. Se há um tratamento individual para cada valor de `j`, ele é redundante.

Tudo é uma questão de conceito, escreva o código para mostrar o que deseja, não para ter menos linhas. Se precisa lidar com itens individualmente faça assim, se precisa tratar os itens como uma sequência (*array*), então os defina assim para usar assim depois.